# What are the 3 all-time best-sellers in each genre?

Tags: fantasy, science-fiction, children, thriller

NOT your personal favorites (subjective)!  The best-sellers (objective).  Group book series together.  Anyone know?  Educated guesses are OK, but documented answers are preferred.

For example, I'm *guessing* that, for sci-fi, the top 3 are the Dune series, the Foundation series, and the Ender series.  Or maybe the Space Odyssey series?  Or, heck, maybe the Star Wars or Star Trek or Honor Harrington series?  See, I don't know!

[For admins: I think this question should have all the genres as tags, but only 5 are allowed.  I could make it 13 different questions, one for each genre, but that seems like gaming the system to gain rep.  Also seems not as useful.  But whatever you want is fine with me.  If this question is handled elsewhere, then let me know, and delete this question.  Thanks.]

Comment: Books that have been around longer will tend to have more sales than new ones. Modern books have a broader market than books that were published fifty years ago. Do you want to account for this? What are you using this information for?

Comment: @dmm Yes, tagging here is limited to five, as is the case across all SE sites. Can you edit the question to include a list of the genres you're interested in, rather than try to squeeze it all into the tags? I agree that multiple separate questions would make no sense.

Comment: And, "best-sellers" by what benchmark? How is it useful to know whether Tolkein beat out Harry Potter, or vice versa? Is Twilight in Romance, Fantasy, or YA? As written, this feels to me like an arbitrary request for arbitrary data.

Comment: You could look at these links and figure most of it out for yourself.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_best-selling_books

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_best-selling_fiction_authors

Comment: @Legion600: Thanks, I will see if I can use those links to give my own answer.

Comment: @NeilFein: OK, will do.

Comment: @Kit: and Standback: I am interested to see what common features are shared by the top sellers.  Yes, #sold is not the only figure of merit, and yes, books cross genres, but one has to start somewhere.

Comment: @dmm: You can easily name some top sellers. Maybe not specifically top 3, but some pretty major ones. Is that helpful to you?

Comment: @Legion600: Can you make your comment an answer?  I'd like to accept it.  Those links are even better than what I asked for.

Comment: @Kit I suspect that "most total sales since they were published" and "most sales this year" could give very different answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could look at these links and figure most of it out for yourself.

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_best-selling_books

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_best-selling_fiction_authors

Comment: Can you please quote the important parts of the links you give? It would make for a much better answer. Also see: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231)

Comment: The only reason I made it an answer was that the original poster asked me too.  To show what is important would basically mean block quoting the entire page.
I was surprised this was even an allowed question as most of the other SE sites don't allow list questions and it showed a seeming lack of any attempt to find an answer since I found this in under a minute.
If you want to delete it go ahead

Comment: This isn't a list question per se, or at least it's more managable. There are only so many genres out there. And this can be answered with a summary.

Comment: Wikipedia lists 21 broad genres of fiction and at least that many of non-fiction depending on how you categorize them.  How are we defining a genre?  Are we going with broad definitions or with bookseller definitions?

Comment: That depends on what @dmm needs, I think. But my guess would be seller categories.

Comment: Well according to this site:
http://www.publishingquestions.com/booktext/genres.html

Barnes and Noble uses 114 different main genre categories.  That's way more effort than I would ever want to put into answering this question.